# Utilizar objeto instanciado en una clase en otra diferente

Tags: c#

Buenas a todos!
¿Puedo utilizar métodos o propiedades de un objeto que tengo instanciado en un espacio de nombres/clase en otra clase que esta dentro de otro espacio de nombres?

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Sí, es posible, solo debes tener la referencia al otro *namespace* para que lo puedas utilizar.

Comment: Instancio una clase dentro de mi clase general y luego, por ejemplo, al realizarse un evento quiero sacar una ventana form nueva, pero quiero que dentro de esta nueva ventana salgan parametros del objeto instanciado en la clase general...
El problema es que no tengo acceso a el ya que esta declarado en la clase general y no en la form nueva, entiendo que no tengo que volver a instanciar nada ya que el objeto ya existe, no quiero una nueva instancia... No se si me explico

Answer (score 1):

si la clase es publica solo necesitas llamarla mediante `namespace` y el constructor

```
 X.B b = new X.B(5);
```

por ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X.B b = new X.B(5);
            b.printSize();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

namespace X
{
    class B
    {
        int a;

        public B(int a)
        {
            this.a=a;
            Console.WriteLine("hola soy x");         
        }

        public int printSize(){
            Console.WriteLine("hola soy x y mi tamaño es " + this.a);
            return this.a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro que puedes usar la instancia de un objeto en otra clase, todo depende de como manejes la relación entre los objetos.

[Aquí](http://ideone.com/dZKw6t) te dejo un link de como llamar métodos en otros objetos.

Y para manejar la parte del NameSpace, [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) una documentación de Microsoft y la copia del ejemplo que ponen ellos.

```
using System;

// Using alias directive for a class.
using AliasToMyClass = NameSpace1.MyClass;

// Using alias directive for a generic class.
using UsingAlias = NameSpace2.MyClass<int>;

namespace NameSpace1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "You are in NameSpace1.MyClass.";
        }
    }

}

namespace NameSpace2
{
    class MyClass<T>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "You are in NameSpace2.MyClass.";
        }
    }
}

namespace NameSpace3
{
    // Using directive:
    using NameSpace1;
    // Using directive:
    using NameSpace2;

    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            AliasToMyClass instance1 = new AliasToMyClass();
            Console.WriteLine(instance1);

            UsingAlias instance2 = new UsingAlias();
            Console.WriteLine(instance2);

        }
    }
}
// Output: 
//    You are in NameSpace1.MyClass.
//    You are in NameSpace2.MyClass.
```

Y para usar como una clase normal, simplemente lo instancias, como lo explican [Aquí](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/3b76bf47-3bb4-42e0-a9d6-dce95ff7031f/clase-esttica-o-instanciada-cuales-son-las-ventajas?forum=vcses):

```
MyClass objeto = new MyClass();
```

En este caso tienes que hacer un constructor para la clase:

```
        class MyClass<T>
    {

        public MyClass()
        {

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "You are in NameSpace2.MyClass.";
        }
    }
```

Puedes consultar mas [Acá](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

**NOTA:** Para el caso de WPF, para poder usar funciones de otra clase hace falta que la clase sea **static class**, por consiguiente, los atributos y funciones deberán ser **static** [ver](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes).